# Failed tag merge resulted in lost tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, moderator-tools

[Spanish Language & Usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) has decided to [convert to Spanish-language tags](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/12), from current English-language tags.

Tonight I tried to do some tag merging, and tried to merge [vocabulary](/questions/tagged/vocabulary) into [vocabulario](/questions/tagged/vocabulario), which failed with an exception I failed to record.

The end result is that some <strike>170-180</strike> 120 questions *lost their tag*.

In the short term, is there any way to restore the old tag on these questions? Or worst case, provide me with a list of the affected questions so they can be manually edited?

And perhaps more fundamentally... shouldn't a tag merge be an atomic operation? Shouldn't a failure not abort the transaction half-way through, in a horribly broken state like this?

Comment: I've added `vocabulario` to all the questions that were tagged `vocabulary` yesterday - you can see the [revisions here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity).

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Thanks for the save!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that you accidentally merged `vocabulary` into `vocabulary` and we didn't validate this action - our bad, big time.

The merge basically burninated that tag from all questions it appeared on, but our backups will allow us to restore the data.  I just have to write an "add tag" function to retag those ~120 questions en masse (gimme tomorrow, por favor!).

I'm pushing out a fix now that prevents this error from occurring again, so moderators won't have to worry about it.

As for tag merges being an atomic transaction, you are correct - **they should be, but aren't currently.**  This will be remedied.