# What would happen if there were a cycle of tag synoynms?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

Asking mostly out of curiosity:

**Question**: What would happen if there were a cycle of tag synoynms?

As in, there are tag synonyms such as a 2-cycle:

- [a](/questions/tagged/a) -> [b](/questions/tagged/b)
- [b](/questions/tagged/b) -> [a](/questions/tagged/a)

or a 3-cycle:

- [a](/questions/tagged/a) -> [b](/questions/tagged/b)
- [b](/questions/tagged/b) -> [c](/questions/tagged/c)
- [c](/questions/tagged/c) -> [a](/questions/tagged/a)

and so on for possibly longer cycle lengths.  I don't think I want to "try and see" (in case it results in an infinite loop).  Perhaps the system disallows this.

Comment: Looks like you don't even need a cycle of two for things to blow up: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145474/self-referencing-synonym (or at least that bug existed 6 to 8 years ago).

Comment: Related incident from a few years ago, although this is was a tag merge: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134862/failed-tag-merge-resulted-in-lost-tags/134873#134873

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That won't happen. If there is even a *pending* synonym from [a](/questions/tagged/a) to [b](/questions/tagged/b), you can't suggest a synonym to [a](/questions/tagged/a) or from [b](/questions/tagged/b). You'll get a message like this when you try:

[image]

Interestingly enough, the message is wrong: it claims the very synonym I'm proposing exists, it should have read

> A synonym from synonym2 to synonym1 exists, chains are not allowed

This is another variation:

[image]

Suggesting a tag as a synonym of itself doesn't work either:

> [image]

Comment: As you're experimenting can you create a synonym1 for synonym1? Did you try this also with mod powers or as regular user?

Comment: @rene recursive synonyms aren't possible either. This is with mod powers (it might have made a difference if the synonyms were pending or active, so I tested on Chess.SE Meta).